# Matlab: how to manage a lot of sparse data with the sparse command?

Tags: matlab, data-structures, initialization, dynamic-data, sparse-matrix

The variable vector stores a multilinear function with 31 variables such that

```
>> tic; mlf=sparse(1,2^31)
toc
tic; mlf(1)=7
toc

mlf =

   All zero sparse: 1-by-2147483648

Elapsed time is 1.075814 seconds.

mlf =

                  (1,1)                       7

Elapsed time is 15.468432 seconds.
```

where it contains all possible terms in the multilinear function such as constant, $x_1$,x_2x_31$ and $x_30x_31$. Yet this initilization and particularly assignment take far too long time -- ~1 second and ~15 seconds here -- in reality each mlf has only about 1-20 terms so not even close to 2147483648! Now the times are far too large apparently due to too many extra zeros.

> **How to manage the large variable vector to store sparse information?**

Comment: If the function is multilinear, why do you need to store 2^31 values? Are not 31 values enough?

Comment: My point is: if the function is multilinear, why do you need all combinations? For example: f(0,1,1) = f(0,0,1) + f(0,1,0) if f is multilinear

Comment: how many non-zeros entries do you have in the matrix? try and pre-allocate space for these non-zeros in `sparse` command.

Comment: @hhh look at the [second example in the doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) where you can specify `nnz`. set `i`, `j` and `s` to be empty, then you can specify size and allocate space for `nnz` entries.

Comment: @Shai you mean like this `sparse([],[],[],1,2^31)` (this takes still a a lot of time to init)?

Comment: @hhh I mean `sparse([],[],[],1,2^31, 500);` (allocating space for 500 non-zero elements).

Comment: @hhh - BTW, have you tried storing the mlf as a column vector rather than a row vector? `sparse([],[],[],2^31, 1, 500);`? If I'm not mistaken this should be easier to handle with Matlab's internal representation of sparse matrices.

Comment: @Shai Amazing! It worked! Moved your comment to an answer to draw more attention,  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19618275/164148.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shai commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609830/matlab-how-to-manage-a-lot-of-sparse-data-with-the-sparse-command?noredirect=1#comment29121827_19609830)

> "BTW, have you tried storing the mlf as a column vector rather than a row vector? sparse([],[],[],2^31, 1, 500);? If I'm not mistaken this should be easier to handle with Matlab's internal representation of sparse matrices."

and that did it!

```
>> tic;sparse([],[],[],2^31,1);toc 
Elapsed time is 0.549435 seconds.
>> tic;sparse([],[],[],1,2^31);toc 
Elapsed time is 15.102854 seconds.
```

Amazing!

#### Why is that so?

(If I'm allowed to so bluntly edit a post) Matlab's sparse matrices are stroed using three vectors: one that stores the row index of the non-zeros entries. The second stores the column index **but in a compressed manner**. Finally, the third vector stores the actual value of each entry.
The first and last vectors always have length as the number of non-zeros elements in the matrix. However, the compressed second one has length as the number of columns of the matrix **regardless of the number of non-zero elements in the matrix**.
Therefore, transposing `mlf` from `2^31` columns to 1 has a **huge** impact on the size of the second vector - and this is why the timing is so drastically affected.